# Wikidata query to select items with both Simple Wikipedia & English Wikipedia Pages

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get Wikidata entries that have both a Simple Wikipedia page, and an English Wikipedia page, and have both of the links. So far I have:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?articleSimple ?article
WHERE {  
  ?articleSimple  schema:about ?item ;
                  schema:isPartOf <https://simple.wikipedia.org/> ;
                  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]" }
}

LIMIT 10
```

[(Link to demo)](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FarticleSimple%20%3Farticle%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3FarticleSimple%20%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fsimple.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0ALIMIT%2010)

Right now, this successfully selects the Simple Wikipedia pages, but I'm not able to get the regular Wikipedia page.
I've tried with an "OPTIONAL" block, or another "schema:about", but have not been successful. Thank you for any help provided!

Comment: just use a second graph pattern for English Wikipedia and share the `item` variable, or what exactly did not work?

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?articleSimple ?article
WHERE {  
  ?articleSimple  schema:about ?item ;
                  schema:isPartOf <https://simple.wikipedia.org/> .
  ?article  schema:about ?item ;
                  schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
                  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]" }
}

LIMIT 10`

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I still have a lot to learn about SPARQL...